# Disable I/O calls during embedded Linux GUI development on desktop

Tags: gcc, embedded-linux

I'm developing an [EGT](https://www.microchip.com/en-us/development-tools-tools-and-software/embedded-software-center/ensemble-graphics-toolkit) embedded Linux application on a Microchip SAM Xplained Board. EGT is primarily C++ based, similar in some respects to Qt. The application I'm building naturally contains the GUI element & the interaction with hardware connected to the board.

For speed & convenience I'd like to develop as much as possible of the GUI on a desktop (EGT will run on a desktop Linux machine), however I'm going to run into issues when hardware interaction occurs (e.g. calls to GPIO pins etc.)

Is there a gcc compile time option to somehow block/redirect/overwrite these hardware interactions to something that would allow the application to run on a desktop? If not I think I'm looking at lots of #if arch = 'ARM' or something similar.

Thanks for looking!

Regards,

Comment: Seems like you are describing a need for a hardware abstraction layer.  IOW do not directly make *"calls to GPIO pins"*, but wrap them in functions that abstract the purpose of the operations.  For the desktop version the HAL functions perform NOPs.

Comment: Thanks, seems like a reasonable way to go.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone looking at this it seems that the way to go is some type of wrapper around hardware calls (examples below) as suggested by @sawdust or using a QEMU (which can be built using [Yocto](https://docs.yoctoproject.org/dev-manual/qemu.html))

```
// Enable compiling on desktop
#if defined(__x86_64__) || defined(_M_X64)
    #pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wunused-value"
    #define GPIO_CHIP_GET_LINE(chip, offset) (NULL)
    #define GPIO_CHIP_OPEN_BY_NAME(port, pin) (1)
    #define GPIO_LINE_REQUEST_OUTPUT(line, consumer, default_val) (1)
    #define GPIO_LINE_REQUEST_INPUT(line, consumer) (1)
    #define GPIO_LINE_SET_VALUE(line, value) (1)
    #define GPIO_LINE_GET_VALUE(line) (1)
    
#else
    #define GPIO_CHIP_GET_LINE(chip, offset) gpiod_chip_get_line(chip, offset)
    #define GPIO_CHIP_OPEN_BY_NAME(name) gpiod_chip_open_by_name(name)
    #define GPIO_LINE_REQUEST_OUTPUT(line, consumer, default_val) gpiod_line_request_output(line, consumer, default_val)
    #define GPIO_LINE_REQUEST_INPUT(line, consumer) gpiod_line_request_input(line, consumer)
    #define GPIO_LINE_SET_VALUE(line, value) gpiod_line_set_value(line, value)
    #define GPIO_LINE_GET_VALUE(line) gpiod_line_get_value(line)
#endif
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).